# If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $|f'(z)| \leq 1$ then $|f(z)| \leq |z|^2/2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that a function $f$ is analytic in the disk $\Delta=\{z \in \Bbb C : |z|<1 \}$, that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, and that $|f'(z)| \leq 1$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$. Prove that $|f(z)| \leq |z|^2/2$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$.

I found an answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533103/a-function-f-is-analytic-in-d-d0-1-and-f0-f0-0) but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I tried to do the following:

For any $z$ in $\Delta$, let $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Delta$ be defined by $\gamma(t)=tz$. Then $\gamma'(t)=z$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ and

$$|f(z)|=|f(z)-f(0)|=|f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))|$$
$$= \left|\int_\gamma f'(w)dw \right| \leq \int_\gamma |f'(w)| |dw| \leq \int_\gamma |dw| = \int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)| dt  = \int_0^1 |z| dt = |z|.$$
So, $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$.
Let $g: \Delta \to \Bbb C$ be defined by $g(z)=f(z)/z$ for $z \neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$. $g$ is continuous in $\Delta$ (since $f'(0)=0$) and analytic in $\Delta \backslash \{0\}$, so it's analytic in $\Delta$.

We have $|g(z)|=|f(z)|/|z| \leq |z|/|z|=1$. So, we can apply Schwarz Lemma to $g$, and we'd have $|g(z)| \leq |z|$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$, which means $|f(z)| \leq |z|^2$.

This is what I did, it's almost done but I can't figure out how to get the $2$ dividing $|z|^2$.

Comment: agree with below answer; I have no explanation why your method loses the 2 though

Comment: I guess Schwarz lemma is one of the many "cheats" you have in complex analysis; applying them to the question assumptions directly is better than doing some inequality that doesn't use the analyticity and then applying Schwarz lemma. That's the best "intuition" I can think of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the relevant part in the linked answer

> $$|f(z)|=\left|\int_{[0,z]}f'(w)dw\right|\leq|z|^{2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}tdt=\dfrac{|z|^{2}}{2}$$

some elaboration ($[0,z]$ is the straight line joining $0$ and $z\in\mathbb C$, using OP's parameterisation)
$$|f(z)|=\left|\int_{[0,z]}f'(w)dw\right| \leq \int_{[0,z]}|f'(w)||dw| = \int_0^1|f'(tz)| |z|dt \le \int_0^1 |tz| |z|dt  = |z|^2\int_{0}^{1}tdt=\dfrac{|z|^{2}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Can't we just apply the Schwarz lemma to $f'$?

Since $f$ is analytic in the unit disc, so is $f'$.  And we have $f'(0) = 0$ and $|f'(z)| \leq 1$ on the unit disc.

It then follows from the Schwarz lemma that $|f'(z)| \leq |z|$ on the unit disc.

Then we can integrate on a straight line path from 0 to whatever point we want, using the fact that for a real function with $|f(x)| < |x|$ and $f(0) = 0$,

$$|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| = \left|\int_0^x f'(t) \, dt\right| \leq \int_0^x |f'(t)| \, dt \leq \int_0^x |t|\, dt = \frac{1}{2}|x|^2$$

Comment: But what real function?

Comment: Well you can still integrate along the straight-line path from 0 to whatever point z on the unit disc like you did in the answer above, and then these bounds apply.  I just wrote the bounds for a real function so that I don't have to lay out exactly what $\gamma$ is, etc.

Comment: Hmm. I think that might be the same little part I didn't understand in the answer of the question that I cited.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You're missing the $f'$ in the integral at the second and third equal signs.

Comment: @Twink the relevant part  in the linked answer $$|f(z)|=\left|\int_{[0,z]}f'(w)dw\right|\leq|z|^{2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}tdt=\dfrac{|z|^{2}}{2}$$
some elaboration ($[0,z]$ is the straight line joining $0$ and $z$, using your parameterisation)
$$|f(z)|=\left|\int_{[0,z]}f'(w)dw\right| \leq \int_{[0,z]}|f'(w)||dw| = \int_0^1|f'(tz)| |z|dt \le \int_0^1 |tz| |z|dt  = |z|^2\int_{0}^{1}tdt=\dfrac{|z|^{2}}{2}$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor And there was light! Thanks. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: Fixed, thanks.