# Possible value of the complex analytic function on the open unit disc to itself.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic  function,$f:\Bbb D\to\Bbb D$, where $\Bbb D$ is open unit disc with center at origin and of radius $1$. If $f(0)=0, f’(0)=0$, then possible value of $f(\frac{1}{2})$ can be

$1.$ $\frac{1}{4}.$

$2.$ $\frac{-1}{4}.$

$3.$ $\frac{1}{3}.$

$4.$ $\frac{-1}{3}.$

I tried by taking $f(z)=\pm z^2$ so that first two options are correct one . But I don’t know exact theory of question . Seems to be a question of Schwartz lemma, but unable to apply . Please help . Thank you .

Comment: $f(z)=4f(\frac{1}{2})z^2$ satisfies the hypothesis, so $f(\frac{1}{2})$ can take any value.

Comment: @Gio I didn’t get yours point ...

Comment: @Gio it can not be any value ...

Comment: @Gio: That is not correct since the codomain of $f$ is restricted to $\Bbb D$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3802426/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself, it seems to be an application of [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). However, that directly does not give the answer. However, inspired by the proof of Schwarz lemma, we can prove the following.

**Claim.** $|f(z)| \le |z^2|$ for all $z \in \Bbb D$.

*Proof.* Define the function $g : \Bbb D \to \Bbb C$ as $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^2}$ for $z \neq 0$ and define it appropriately at $0$ so that it is holomorphic. (What will we define it as?)

For $0 < r < 1$, let $D_r$ denote the closed disc of radius $r$ centred at the origin. The maximum modulus theorem implies that there exists $z_r$ on the boundary of $D_r$ such that $|g(z)| \le |g(z_r)|$ for all $z \in D_r$. Thus, we get $$\left\lvert\frac{f(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert = |g(z)| \le |g(z_r)| = \left\lvert\frac{f(z_r)}{z_r^2}\right\rvert \le \left\lvert \frac{1}{r^2}\right\rvert,$$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that $f$ maps into $\Bbb D$ and $|z_r| = r$.

Now, given any $z \in \Bbb D$, we see that $$|f(z)| \le \frac{1}{r^2}|z^2|,$$
for all $r$ satisfying $|z| < r < 1$. Taking the limit $r \to 1^-$ proves the result.

---

Thus, we can eliminate the options of $\pm \frac13$ since $\frac13 > \frac14 = \left(\frac12\right)^2$.

On the other hand, you have noted that $\pm \frac14$ are both possible by considering $f(z) = \pm z^2$.

Comment: thank you . But  it’s 5 minutes question ... I thought it takes less time ....

Comment: @neelkanth: It does take no time if you remember the proof of Schwarz.